# How to add/remove buttons to Nautilus toolbar?

Tags: nautilus

I'd like to add some buttons (such as cut, copy, paste, new folder, open terminal in current folder) to Nautilus Toolbar. Can I?

And it'd be awesome if I could add custom buttons running commands I specify, and perfect if I could use macros (like current selected file full name substitution etc.) in those commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 10.04/10.10/11.04

It can be done in a hacky way by editing `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-navigation-window-ui.xml`. You'll want to look into the part that begins with `<toolbar name="Toolbar">`.

Comment: Doesn't work on 14.04

Answer (score 7):

There is no option to customize the toolbar, but there is [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/13119) requesting it. Feel free to increase the bug's visibility using the "This bug affects me" feature.

Comment: Nice find, but Gnome have already marked that bug as "Won't Fix" so it's incredibly unlikely that Ubuntu/Canonical devs will now add that back in again.  Another Gnome regression IMO, but after 6 years of watching this happen, it doesn't surprise me any more.  Doesn't make me any less bitter... just doesn't surprise me.  :-)